# g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wplacement-new'

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Recently, I am trying to compile a project with a dependency package called "dealii", but I keep getting this error when compiling:

g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wplacement-new'

It seems that g++ does not recognize the option -Wplacement-new. Then I looked at the documentation for gcc, it says -Wplacement-new is a legal warning option flag. But when I invoke "gcc -Wplacement-new ./a.c" I still get this kind of error.

My g++, etc are the latest version. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: There are differences between g++ and gcc. Some flags from gcc are not recognized by g++

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when I tries "gcc -Wplacement-new ./a.c" I still get the same error

Comment: I was able to compile using this file like this: `g++ -L-Wplacement-new=2 main.cpp` It's a flag to the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: OK, got it! Thanks a lot :)